# Java NullPointerExpection Problems

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

So, I'm pretty sure I did everything correctly, but when I run my program, it gives me this log:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.BLANK.handler.ButtonHandler.<init>(ButtonHandler.java:19)
    at com.BLANK.BLANKScreen.<init>(BLANKScreen.java:28)
    at com.BLANK.BLANKWindow.<init>(BLANKWindow.java:28)
    at com.BLANK.BLANKWindow.main(BLANKWindow.java:11)
```

Here's the code that's giving me errors in the ButtonHandler class:

```
public Button button;

public int buttonX = button.x;
public int buttonY = button.y;
public int buttonSizeX = button.xSize;
public int buttonSizeY = button.ySize;
```

And here's the button integers that it's referring to:

```
public int x;
public int y;
public int xSize;
public int ySize;

public Button(int x, int y, int xSize, int ySize, String s, Graphics g) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.xSize = xSize;
    this.ySize = ySize;
}
```

Anyone have any ideas as to what I am doing wrong and how I could fix it?

P.S. If you need any more code snippets just tell me and I'll provide them.

Comment: And what is the content of `button.x` if the button is not initialized at this point?

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize a variable before you use it ... 
By doing this you will get an null pointer

```
public Button button;
public int buttonX = button.x;
```

Because button is not initialized yet.
button is null and you get a null pointer when you try to perform some action on an object which is null.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

When you declare this:

```
public Button button;

public int buttonX = button.x;
```

You are creating and initializing the fields of a class:

- `button` does not have any initialization, so it defaults to `null`
- `buttonX` is supposed to be assigned `button.x`, but this expression is trying to get the field of a `null` object, which causes NPE (this is the very meaning of this exception)

### Solution

The direct solution would be to initialize `button` before declaring the other fields. But from what I see you'd rather not use fields to "store" `button.x`. Use `button.x` directly where needed.

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring a Button:

```
public Button button;
```

and without initializing it you're trying to assign:

```
public int buttonX = button.x;
```

which gives you NPE because `button` is still `null`

Answer (score 1):

If this

```
public Button button;

public int buttonX = button.x;
public int buttonY = button.y;
public int buttonSizeX = button.xSize;
public int buttonSizeY = button.ySize;
```

is a consecutive code block and there are no lines of code between these, then your code can't work.
You declare a new variable `button`. This variable will be initialized with `null` by default. After that you try to access a property of that variable which is `null` at this point. This causes your `NullPointerException`.

To have accurate access to a property you need to initialize the variable correctly.

```
public Button button = new Button(x, y, xSize, ySize, string, graphics);
```